# Error: request entity too large in graphql services of node

Tags: node.js, graphql, body-parser

I am working on node based graphql project, trying to send base64 format image to server.

I am using bodyparser module and configured it as bellow.

```
app.use(bodyparser.text({type: 'application/graphql'}));

app.use(bodyparser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

I am able to send base64 images by direct node services but when it come to graphql services, it is throwing error as:

> Error: request entity too large

Comment: Try set the type. 
  var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({   extended:true,limit:1024*1024*20,type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoding' })

Comment: Thanq for your response @digit, I tried it but it nor worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

For the sake of helping others who are using graphql-yoga npm package. The syntax to add bodyparser option is quite different and I took hours debugging & trying to make it work so adding the code here for reference :

```
const { GraphQLServer } = require("graphql-yoga");

const server = new GraphQLServer({
  schema,  //Your schema
  context, //Your context
});

const options = {
  port: 1234
  bodyParserOptions: { limit: "10mb", type: "application/json" },
};

server.start(options, () =>
  console.log(
    "Server is running\m/" 
  )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `graphql-express` npm package?

If so then the issue is likely this line:
https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql/blob/master/src/parseBody.js#L112

As you can see this sets a max size of 100kb for the request.

We ran into the same issue and fixed it by forking the repository and manually increased the max request size.

This might be a nice opportunity to contribute to the package though!
It would be nice if the limit were configurable.

Comment: Hi, thanq for your response, am using "graphql" module, not "graphql-express" module.

Comment: Ahh okay interesting. Often you will use both packages at the same time. The `graphql` package deals with the schema, types, resolvers, etc while `express-graphql` takes a schema created from the `graphql` package and exposes it to the internet via an express web server.

Comment: hi, the link you provided is not found can you please update.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I specified the uploads and it worked:

```
const options = {
  uploads: {
    maxFieldSize: 1000000000,
    maxFileSize: 1000000000
  }
}
```

`bodyParser` only works with `req.body` and in your case you're handling multipart form